# How to bind data to ListBox Control dynamically?

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding, windows-phone-7, listbox

I am developing window phone 7 application. I am new to the silverlight. I am trying to bind a List of strings to Listbox. I am using the following code

```
ObservableCollection<String> abc = new ObservableCollection<String>();
            abc.Add("XYZ");
            IncomeSummaryListBox.ItemsSource = abc;
```

My xaml contains the following code

```
<ListBox Margin="16,217,6,275" Name="IncomeSummaryListBox">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

With the above code my listbox shows no items at runtime. My emulator device doesn't show anything in listbox. What is wrong in my code ? Can you please provide me any code or link for the above issue so that I can resolve the above issue ? If I am doing anything wrong then please guide me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've not actually told the data template to display the item.  In this simple case of displaying strings if you just delete the whole `ListBox.ItemTemplate` from your xaml it will start working.

For academic reasons you could use:-

```
<ListBox Margin="16,217,6,275" Name="IncomeSummaryListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This binds the `Text` property of a `TextBlock` to an item from the ItemsSource.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to display your items horizontally instead of vertically (as it looks like you may be trying to do), you'll want to replace the ItemsPanelTemplate instead of the DataTemplate.

```
<ListBox Margin="16,217,6,275" Name="IncomeSummaryListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanelTemplate >
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanelTemplate >
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Thats a good call that in fact Shailesh is probably looking for `ItemsPanelTemplate` property.  However it is not necessary nor possible to set `IsItemsHost` property (its readonly).  Also it would be better to use the `VirtualizingStackPanel` (as is used by default) with Orientation set to Horizontal.

Comment: Oops, pulled the IsItemsHost from some of my WPF code [Removed].  Good point with VirtualizingStackPanel.