# Data Binding SQLIte to Listbox(containing three controls) Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, xaml, windows-phone-8

Iam  new  to  implementing  SQLITE  DB   & windows  phone  8   app development...

Implemeted  following  startegy  to  retreive  data  to  listbox which  contains  three other  controls..

here  is  my  XAML  code..

```
<ListBox Height="Auto"   Name="TaskListBox" Margin="5,61,-1,298">

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="Red" Height="480" Width="200">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding status }" Name="team1Name" Width="120" ></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding CreationDate }" Name="team3Name" Foreground="White" Width="120"  HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                        <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding Merid_FK }" Name="team2Name" Foreground="White"/>
                       <TextBlock Text="{Binding status}" Name="venue" Foreground="White" Height="67" Width="78"></TextBlock>
                    </Grid>

                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

        </ListBox>
```

and  my code  behind

```
 private void Insert_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)      
    {

        using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(DB_PATH))
        {

    db.RunInTransaction(() =>
            {
db.Insert(new tasks() { Merid_FK = 126745, status = "Y", CreationDate = DateTime.Now });
db.Insert(new tasks() { Merid_FK = 1289906, status = "N", CreationDate = DateTime.Now });
 });
}

 private void Retrieve_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)      
    {
        List<tasks> listmerchant = dbConn.Query<tasks>("SELECT * from tasks where status='" + "Y" + "'").ToList<tasks>();
      TaskListBox.ItemsSource = listmerchant;
}
```

my tasks class

```
public sealed class tasks
{
    //[PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
    public int Merid_FK { set; get; }
    public string status { set; get; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { set; get; }
  public override string ToString()
    {

        return Merid_FK + ">> " + status + ">> " + CreationDate.ToShortDateString() ;
    }
}
```

my  problem  is  ,iam  getting output as "16757 >> status1 >> 2012-12-20 12:20" on    UI(in  list  box place.. not  at the  controls  in  data  template).. its  simply  returning method placed  in class tasks..please tell me  how  to  bind  data  to  controls  placed  inside  the  lsitbox.
i  already  followed  lot  of similar  questions in  stack over  flow,..

[Slect data  from  SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21956476/select-data-from-sqlite-database-and-binding-values-to-listbox-item-in-windows-p)

[bind  data  to list  box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880429/how-to-bind-data-to-listbox-in-wp7)

[bind  data  dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584687/how-to-bind-data-to-listbox-control-dynamically)

Comment: It does not appear that you're actually getting a task object returned. You should test this by creating some hardcoded tasks objects and see if they render.  If they do, then you'll know that the query isn't returning the proper information.

I think the problem is that you're selecting only status and not the other members of the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please keep  height  and  width  of listbox  and   controls  inside  listbox  to "Auto" in  xaml.if  you  used  any border control..make  sure width  and  height  are  set  to  "Auto"

```
Height="Auto" Width="Auto"
```

please  check  this  and  revert  back  with  error  picture..